# Why it appears undefined when the number is valid?

Tags: javascript

I have this code to ask for a number to show in a td. But its not working properly.

The user should only be able to enter a value between the min and max passed in the func1. And the number must be a valid number.

If these conditions are met the td should should show the number entered by the user, otherwise it should appear again the prompt for the user enter a valid number.

The code is working if the user enter a valid number at first, for example in this case the min is 1 and the max is 10, if the user enter a number betwene these two values it works, the number entered by the user appears on the td. However if the user enters for example the number 0, it appears the message "The value 0 is not valid" and it appears again the prompt, and this is correct. However then if the user enter a valid number like 1 it appears undefined instead of 1 in the td.

Do you know why?

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>Number</td>
    <td id="tdNumber"></td>
    <td>
        <button onclick="func1()">Add</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
let config = {
  numberX: NUMBER_X
}

function showConfig() {
  document.getElementById(TD_NUMBER).innerHTML = config.numberX;
}

function func1() {
  config.numberX = func2(1, 10, P_CONSTANT);
  showConfig();
}

function func2(min, max, p = P_CONSTANT) {
  var number = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number between " + min + "and " + max));
  if (!Number.isInteger(number)) {
    alert("The number " + number + " is not valid.");
    func1();
  } else if (number > max || number < min) {
    alert("The number " + number + " is not valid");
    func1();
  } else {
    return number;
  }
}
```

Comment: With "return number" after call the func1(), if the user enters a invalid number at first and then enters a valid number, the number that appears on the td is the previous incorrect number.

Comment: what is `NUMBER_X` and `P_CONSTANT` ?

Comment: The number_x constant value is 10 and p_constant value is a text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've written your `func1` and `func2`, they can call each other an unlimited number of times. So imagine this case:

1. `func1()` is called (call this `func1_A`)
2. `func1_A` calls `func2()` to get the number (this is `func2_B`)
3. user enters invalid number, `func2_B` starts another call of `func1` (`func1_C`)
4. this new invocation `func1_C` calls `func2()` to get a new number (`func2_D`)
5. user enters valid number, `func2_D` returns it, `func1_C` assigns it to `numberX`
6. `func1_C` returns, execution returns to `func2_B` which has been waiting, `func2_B` has nothing left to do so it returns `undefined`
7. `func1_A` gets `undefined` from `func2_B` and assigns it to `numberX`

Basically, the fact that you have these functions calling each other will keep adding *new* invocations to the stack which the *old* ones have to wait on before they can return. And importantly, the old ones will resume - this means the last thing to happen will always be `func1` assigning the most recent return value of `func2`, which if the user *ever* entered an invalid number, will be `undefined`.

---

Pointy is right: this is a very poor format and is prone to a lot of issues. It isn't an approach you should pursue. At minimum your code shouldn't be needlessly prone to stack overflow errors by having unnecessary recursive function calls.

You can simplify this a lot with a `while` loop. I'm also a fan of meaningful names, and `func1`/`func2` are as far away from meaningful as you can get, so I've renamed the functions.

```js
const NUMBER_X = 10;
const P_CONSTANT = "???";
const TD_NUMBER = "tdNumber";

let config = {
  numberX: NUMBER_X
};

function showConfig() {
  console.log(document.getElementById(TD_NUMBER));
  document.getElementById(TD_NUMBER).innerHTML = config.numberX;
}

function setNumber() {
  config.numberX = getValidNumber(1, 10, P_CONSTANT);
  showConfig();
}

function getValidNumber(min, max, p = P_CONSTANT) {
  var isValid = false;
  var number;

  do {
     number = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number between " + min + " and " + max));
     if(!Number.isInteger(number)) {
        alert("The number " + number + " is not valid.");
     } else if(number > max || number < min) {
        alert("The number " + number + " is not valid");
     } else {
        isValid = true;
     }
  } while(!isValid);

  return number;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Number</td>
     <td id="tdNumber"></td>
    <td><button onclick="setNumber()">Add</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I  typed `abc` and the message was `The number NaN is not valid.`... and I typed `5.2` and I get `5` on display...  this is the poorest code example I have ever encountered :-(

Comment: @MisterJojo both symptoms of passing the user input directly to `parseInt` and can be considered out of scope for this question. Similarly, both of our answers result in bad outputs if the user presses "cancel" on the prompt, but that too is out of scope :-P

Comment: that's right, but I couldn't resist sending you a (friendly) spade ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your program is the real problem. It could probably be made to work, but it's simply not the way to do it. Instead, have `func2()` return some value that indicates an invalid number, and do the iteration inside `func1()`:

```
const INVALID = {};
function func1() {
  let p;
  for (p = func2(1, 10); p === INVALID; p = func2(1, 10)) {
    alert("Invalid value");
  }
  config.numberX = p;

  showConfig();
}

function func2(min, max, p = P_CONSTANT) {

  var number = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number between " + min + "and " + max));

  if(!Number.isInteger(number)){
     return INVALID;
  }

  if(number > max || number < min){
     return INVALID;
  }


  return number;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `{}` it may be better to use a `Symbol()`, since your usage is closer to the designed purpose of symbols than to the purpose of empty objects.

Comment: @CherryDT I'm a fan of the Symbol type, but no two objects created with `{}` will ever be `===` to each other, nor will any other value be `===`. Also Symbol is not supported in IE11.

Comment: `Symbol() !== Symbol()` (or any other value) as well. And I don't see any requirement here to support an outdated browser. I think that by default we should teach up-to-date language usage, unless there is a specific reason not to. Or am I missing something here in regards to the `===` reason you mentioned?

Comment: @CherryDT Like I said, using a Symbol would be fine. However, it doesn't really work any better in a practical sense than `{}`, and `{}` will work in any browser version. I don't know anything about the OP; there are a surprising number of people in the world still supporting IE9, and IE11 remains extremely common in corporate environments.

Comment: Oh sorry then I misunderstood, I thought you meant a symbol would work in this case but be not as good because it's not `!==` everything else, which I didn't understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

when `func1` calls `func2`,
`func1` waits for a response.

If the entry is wrong `func1` never gets its answer because `func2` calls `func1` again...

In total this makes **2** `func1` functions which both **await a response**,
and if the new entry is wrong this will make it a third;

Only the last one on this **stack** will get a return,
while all the others `func1` will continue to wait in vain

the correct way to code this is:

```js
const tdNumber   = document.getElementById('td-number')
  ,   NUMBER_X   = 10
  ,   minVal     = 1
  ,   maxVal     = 10
  ,   config     = { numberX: NUMBER_X }
  ;
function setNumber()
  {
  let numberStr = ''
    , numberIn  = 0
    , badEntry  = true
    ;
  do
    {
    numberStr = prompt( "Enter a number between " + minVal + "and " + maxVal )
    numberIn  = parseFloat( numberStr )
    badEntry  = ( !Number.isInteger( numberIn ))
                || numberIn < minVal
                || numberIn > maxVal
                ;
    if ( badEntry )
      { alert("The number " + numberStr + " is not valid") }
    }
  while ( badEntry )

  tdNumber.textContent = config.numberX = numberIn
  }
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 1em;
  }
td {
  border: solid grey 1px;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align : center;
  }
#td-number {
  width : 4em
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Number</td>
    <td id="td-number"></td>
    <td><button onclick="setNumber()">Add</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this has to be among the most upsetting code styles I think I've seen pretty much ever. :-(

Comment: @Klaycon thank you, I take it as a compliment, this style is called Whitesmiths or Haskell, can be a little extrapolated (I'm still looking for complete documentation) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Whitesmiths_style

Comment: the Whitesmith braces are the least upsetting to me compared to the inconsistent semicolon use (some statements are followed by semicolon, others rely on ASI), inconsistent variable casing (camel case, screaming case, title case all used seemingly without pattern), inconsistent spacing (spaces around arguments to `parseFloat` but nowhere else), inconsistent braces (`do {` has brace on same line, contradicting whitesmith style), misleading variable naming (`OnError` sounds like an event but is a flag), and nondescript function naming (`func1` means nothing)

Comment: @Klaycon ah, it's true, it's true, my style is still imperfect and thank you for the criticism, but I started to question this question because of the commas on JS objects: they are less visible at the end of lines and this produces errors, at least at the beginning of the line I am sure I will not forget them. it's a bit the same for the braces and the rest, after I realize that the way to a real style will be much longer, but what is certain is that the K&R and derivatives style are not suitable for directly viewing comma and brace errors

Comment: it does make sense, I admit this comma style is actually somewhat pleasing and I think all of my discomfort with it is just having not seen it before. Not a fan of the braces and semicolons still, but I appreciate the reasoning behind it at least - sorry for nitpicking so much!

Comment: @Klaycon no problem, it was my pleasure to discuss this subject ;-)